# Problems with track and attach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
foreach (var memo in album64.Album_Share_Text)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        //album_Share_TextRepository.Attach(memo);
                        album_Share_TextRepository.Delete(memo);
                        album_Share_TextRepository.SaveChanges();
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

if attach :  An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

if delete : The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

I can find by id and delete, but I want evade the second query on sql server, I want best way with minimum cost.

Comment: var toDelete = new Album_Share_Text { id_Album = memo.id_Album, id_Album_Share_Text = memo.id_Album_Share_Text };
                            album_Share_TextRepository.Attach(toDelete);